# Game time in Javascript Browser Game

Tags: javascript, time

I'm fairly new to javascript and programming at all, to be honest. I know html and css and the basics of javascript and I'm trying to figure out how time works in js.

I would like to make a simple game where the user can take care of a horse. And every action he does (i.e brushing the mane) would take a specific amount of time. Let's say five minutes for that. How do I code that?

Would be really thankful if anyone could tell me. Thank you in advance.

Jolly

Answer (score 0):

just get the time in the future when the even would be finished at.

use this function

```js
function getTime(numOfHours) {
   let date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime() + numOfHours * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  return date;
}
```

then do check in your game logic to see if the event end time against the current time.

```js
let endEventTime = getTime(0,00138); // add 5 seconds to the current time
// do a loop or some setTimeout() login and once the time passes then let your user do another action.
```